# TypeScript and additional values for types

Tags: typescript

I started to write a checker for source text files and line in such a file is defined in TypeScript  Schema. And in this text files field marked as a z.boolean coud be different then only "true" and "false". It coud be "T" and "F" or "Yes" and "No". How coud I modify Scripts to fullfill such a requirement? I mean proper values for fields z.boolean in case of TRUE could be "T" or "Yes" not only "true"?

E.g.
I have text file with 3 lines, Each line have three fields:

```
111|Aaa|true 
222|Bbb|false 
333|Ccc|true
```

and I can define in schema

```
fied1: z.number() 
field2: z.string() 
field3: z.boolean
```

and parse will success. But in case of file like

```
111|Aaa|Yes 
222|Bbb|No 
333|Ccc|Yes
```

parse will be not proper. And I want to modify schema to make it parse proper

And one more question - I have string with define length and I want to define for this string proper characters in it. For example proper is string with big letters and numbers I mean string "ABC123" is proper but string ""ABc123" is inproper. How can I modify type string in schema to do it?

Comment: It’s not clear what exactly you’re asking.  Could you provide a [mre] that demonstrates your situation?

Comment: Ofcourse I have text file with 3 lines, Each line have three fields:
111|Aaa|true
222|Bbb|false
333|Ccc|true
and I can define in schema
fied1: z.number()
field2: z.string()
field3: z.boolean
and parse will success.
But case of file like
111|Aaa|Yes
222|Bbb|No
333|Ccc|Yes
parse will be not proper. And I want to modify schema to make it parse proper.

Comment: This is basically a coersible enum. read more on enums and transform.

Comment: what "schema"?  What's `z`?  Is that zod? If so, and your question depends on it, you might want to tag the question as such so that the right people see it.

Comment: zod does have regex validators, check those

Comment: "And one more question"  Please ask one question only.  Otherwise it might be closed as needing focus.

Comment: Right it's my fault that I only wrote TypeScript and not Zod validation library.

Comment: And right again - regex is solution in both cases - big senkju!